# What is the meaning of this co-efficient in the formula for the width of the d-band center?

Tags: density-of-states, d-band

In this article where they have introduced a new activity descriptor [width of d-band](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11244-013-0159-2) the formula for width has a coefficient 4 $(W_d = 4\sqrt{m^c_2})$. While the same formula used in other works does not have any coefficient $(W_d = \sqrt{m^c_2})$. It is understood that the formula is the second moment, but why in this article the coefficient is taken?

Comment: Could you point to some of the works that use the alternative convention?

Comment: Please find the link where they have used the alternate form, http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.045414